# AppleScript - Get the path to an application without opening it

Tags: applescript, path

I need to store the path to Chromium to use later in the script, however running `set chromium to (POSIX path of (path to application "Chromium"))` in AppleScript Editor opens the application. How can I store the path to the application without causing the application to open. Hard coding the path worked, but I wanted to be able to find the application path instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use Finder to get an application file object:

```
tell application "Finder"
    POSIX path of (application file id "org.chromium.Chromium" as alias)
end tell
```

You can also get the bundle identifier with `id of app "Chromium"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reference the applications folder path and then append the path to Chromium. The application should not open with this method either.

```
set chromium to POSIX path of ((path to applications folder as text) & "Chromium.app")
```